Audio File Embedding in a Go High Level Website
Has anyone successfully embedded an audio file in a website built in Go High Level? What format file did you use? Does it auto play and loop? I've tried to embed all kinds of HTML codes and file formats but nothing seems to work for me.
I've looked everywhere for a code that works or even a work around.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
